# Classic Analytics or Universal Analytics Tracking Code

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to evaluate whether or not the Google Analytics tracking code that's implemented is Universal or Classic. The account was upgraded to Universal, but from what I have researched, I don't think the tracking code was upgraded from Classic to Universal.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7431679-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'website.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: That code is for [Classic Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for classic analytics. Universal analytics will always use their javascript file name analytics.js . Here's an example of the code

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-7431679-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Simply switching in Google Analytics doesn't fully make the change, to complete making the switch you need to change out your code above with the new one.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure it out with a little more googling. This just helped confirm everything. Thanks!